# multiple CUPS servers depending on network

Tags: cups

I'm running an Ubuntu 18.04 machine with CUPS 2.2.7 installed (distribution default). My company provides a centralized CUPS server to access all printers of the facility. However, I only get the system working correctly by setting the `CUPS_SERVER` environment variable in `/etc/environment`. Then again, I cannot access any further printers (for instance: directly attached to my system and managed by my local CUPS server) simultaneously. My solution for now is to enable/disable the according line in `/etc/environment` depending on my situation and reboot the system every time I want to access facility or local printers.

I am pretty sure there is a way to use multiple servers simultaneously, but I could not figure it out yet.

Comment: It is not clear why you need several cup daemons in the same server.

Comment: I don't. I need a single client (my PC) to access multiple servers (remote + local) so I can access facility-managed printers as well as printers directly attached to my machine.